# call a Frame2 from a button in Frame1

Tags: python, button, wxpython, frame

I'am a new bie in python,I have to call a frame "Frame2" when I clic on a button from Frame1,I have this error:

[image]

this I my code:

```
global Frame2 fr
 def OnButton4Button(self, event):

        fr.Show()
        even.Skip()
```

NB:I work with wxpython,and boa constructor
thanks fro help

Comment: did you see that you have an indentation typo between the two first lines that should be aligned on the same column

Comment: and please apply [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommendations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several typos in your code. Here's a corrected example:

```
from Frame2 import fr
def OnButton4Button(self, event):
    fr.Show()
    event.Skip()  # you need to spell event correctly
```

This assumes that **Frame2** is a module. Most of the time, you don't need to use globals in Python.

To make this a bit easier to follow, I wrote an example that has a MainFrame class and a Frame2 class in the same module so you don't have to import anything or use globals:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class Frame2(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Frame2")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)



########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Main Frame")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        button = wx.Button(panel, label="Open Frame2")
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)
        self.Show()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onButton(self, event):
        """"""
        frame = Frame2()
        frame.Show()
        event.Skip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your short code you have an indentation on the second line, this is an error, you must write it like:

```
from Frame2 import fr
def OnButton4Button(self, event):

        fr.Show()
        event.Skip()
```

You may respect the indentation in Python like following example:

```
global var
def function():
    #indented block
    #should be always on the same column
    condition = 1
    if condition:
        #new indented block
        #is also aligned on a column
        print "something"
    #this is out of the IF block
#call the function
function()
```

In the [PEP8 recommendations](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) you will find the rules to avoid indenting errors.

Comment: thanks daouzli but I still have this problem in global Frame2 fr :(

Comment: indeed, `global Frame2 fr` is not valid in Python. If the aim is to define 2 global variables, it should be written `global Frame2, fr`.

Comment: but if Frame2 is a module, and fr an element of the module you may import fr from your module like that: `from Frame2 import fr`